Why do pump.fun coins move to raydium once the bonding curve is "filled"?
I'm trying to understand the mechanics of pump.fun's token launch system. According to their site:
How it works
Pump prevents rugs by making sure that all created tokens are safe. Each coin on pump is a fair-launch with no presale and no team allocation.
step 1: pick a coin that you like
step 2: buy the coin on the bonding curve
step 3: sell at any time to lock in your profits or losses
step 4: when enough people buy on the bonding curve it reaches a market cap of $69k
step 5: $12k of liquidity is then deposited in raydium and burned

I understand the bonding curve mechanism for initial sales, but why move the trading to Raydium at the end? Why not keep trading on pump.fun? Why wouldn't they want to own the vertical and continue to market make? What's the purpose of this transition?

because at the end bcs are bcs and  we need to move to the Amms system which works with liquidity pools which also exists only in higher boys like raydium. it is not feasible to add Amms in pump.fun because if they do that they should ask the dev to depose the liquidity at the time of creation which they don't want to do. in fact they can create the Amms and handle after graduating things but it needs the whole intensive resources to be the dex
